# what is going on in this map: $\phi: G \rightarrow GL(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a group $G$ of finite order and $V = \mathbb{C}^n$.  What exactly would be meant by the following map:

$\phi: G \rightarrow GL(V)$?

I see that each group element would be assigned a matrix in this space $GL(V)$, but how would such a matrix be determined from the element $g$?  Is that even pertinent?  And what would such a matrix do to some vector $v$ from $V$?

Comment: Usually this would be a group homomorphism if we're considering such maps. $\phi(gh)=\phi(g)\phi(h)$.

Comment: right, but let's say I need to say something about $\phi(g)v$, I what would the action of $\phi(g)$ on $v$ be?

Comment: The study of such maps (provided they're homomorphisms, as Matt Samuel points out) is the content of an entire branch of mathematics called representation theory (and its offshoot, character theory, which is perhaps surprisingly about as content-laden!).

Comment: This is another to say the group operates on the vector space.

Comment: Well, it acts as $\phi(g)$, which is a matrix. Without knowing $\phi$ you don't know exactly how in advance of course.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups

Comment: I see, and all we know is that the matrix is invertible, right?

Comment: Yes, and the goal of representation theory is in part to classify all possible such homomorphisms for a given group.

Comment: There is actually a lot that can be said without knowing the specific map. For the finite group example, the eigenvalues must be $k$th roots of unity, where $k$ divides the order of the element. If two elements are conjugate, then they have the same trace, etc.